# Ratio Recommended Paging Space

Tags: linux, memory, memory-usage, virtual-memory

How would you find the approximate ratio of recommended paging space to RAM size? and does the currently allocated paging space= recommended? Where is the recommended paging space? I used the top command and got

KiB Mem: 1016476 total,     171668 free,    439328 used,    4054580 buff/cahce
KiB Swap: 3999740 total,    3999740 free,    0 used,         399924 avail Mem

Answer (score 0):

Have so much memory in the box so that the system practically never uses swap. Then, to prepare for the worst case, you can have some swap allocated.

Generally, in business environment production use, there is no relation between installed RAM size and allocated swap. If one encounters swapping in normal use, then the system is not good enough for the use.

Furthermore, general RAM usage depends entirely on the application(s) running in the box. In some use cases like workstations, swap usage can be tolerated if it doesn't interfere with the workflow.